# SubItems[index] not working

Tags: c#, listview

I want to get the subitem of a specific item,

```
textBox1.Text = item.SubItems[1].Text;
```

Lately, I've been having problems with `item.SubItems[index]`. I can't get or set the value, although I have found a workaround for setting the value. I still can't get, however. I've looked it up and nobody has seemed to have the same problem so I'm sure I'm doing something obvious wrong. I just have no idea what's going on.

EDIT:

There's no error at all. The program continues to run like nothing went wrong, except textBox1.Text isn't set to the subitem text. Item is a listviewitem. Here's some code:

```
 foreach (ListViewItem item in ths.listView1.SelectedItems)
        {
            textBox1.Text = item.Text;

            numericUpDown1.Value = Convert.ToDecimal(item.SubItems[1]);
            comboBox1.Text = item.SubItems[2].Text;
            textBox3.Text = item.SubItems[3].Text;
            ths.listView1.Items.Remove(item);
        }
```

ths is Form1.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: have you tried .Content instead

Comment: What is `item`? What's actually going wrong? It would really help if you'd give a lot more information - ideally a *short* but complete program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: How many columns has the listview? They are zero indexed item.SubItems[0].Text or just item.Text

Comment: sorry...there's no error message. Nothing at all. Also, when I'm debugging with a breakpoint, whenever I reach such a line, the program automatically continues. I'm not sure why.

Comment: You can't remove the item from inside a foreach loop. Use for(int i=listView1.SelectedItems.Count-1; i >= 0; i--)

Answer (score 0):

I notice that you are in a loop over `listView1.SelectedItems`, displaying each item.

This does not make sense. Even if there is a selection you probably should pull out only the values for one listviewitem.

The second error in our code is that you are `Removing` the loop item from the ListView. While you are using two 'different' collections, namely `SelectedItems` and `Items` you are still modifying the iterator, which is a no-go.

So you need to define what you want to achieve: Delete all Selected Items or display the content of one item?

To delete all selected items can be done like this:

```
while (listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0) 
       listView1.Items.Remove(listView1.SelectedItems[0]);
```

Maybe you want to display the values for the last item you deleted..?? If so here is how:

```
while (listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0) 
{
   if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count == 1)
   {
       ListViewItem item = listView1.SelectedItems[0];
       textBox1.Text = item.Text;
       numericUpDown1.Value = Convert.ToDecimal(item.SubItems[1]);
       comboBox1.Text = item.SubItems[2].Text;
       textBox3.Text = item.SubItems[3].Text;
   }
   listView1.Items.Remove(listView1.SelectedItems[0]);
}
```

Comment: My goal is to display the item that's selected. My main problem is with item.SubItems[index].Text. It doesn't work at all - there's no error when I use the code but it doesn't work.

Comment: Solved the problem...uh...I tried to convert a subItem to a decimal! Stupid me...